# Max validator value using the value of another control within a form array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I am hoping the code below explains my need well.  I need a max number validator on a count field that checks for the value of another capacity field.  An issue I am having is both fields are within a form array of a form group, so there will be many instances of count/capacity combinations.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Using Angular 7.

```
setForm() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    types: this.fb.array([])
  });
  this.typesArray = this.form.get('types') as FormArray;
}

addType() {
  this.typesArray.push(this.setType(0,0));
}

setType(countValue, capacityValue): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    count: [{value: countValue}, [
      Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]*$/i ),
      Validators.max(WHAT PUT HERE FOR ALWAYS CHECKING VALUE OF CAPACITY??)
    ]],
    capacity: [{value: capacityValue}, Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]*$/i )],
  });
}
```

I would expect the validation message to show in the UI if the count field is greater than capacity field at any time of editing either of the fields.  This would be a connection only between each instance of both.

Comment: The validator shouldn't be on the count control. Otherwise it will only be called when the count changes, but not when the capacity changes. Put it on the form group itself. See the answer for an example custom validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you try to validate a form control based on another form control the best case is to create custom formgroup validator

custom validator

```js
export function maxValueValidator(fb: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
  const count = +fb.get('count').value || 0;
  const capacity = +fb.get('capacity').value;

  if (capacity > count) {
    return {
      maxValue:
      {
        count,
        capacity
      }
    }
  } else {
    null
  }

}
```

add the validator to the formGroup

```
this.form = fb.group({
  count: null,
  capacity: [null,]
}, {  //  after we have finished set the controls we add formGroup validators
    validators: [maxValueValidator] 
  });
```

}

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-value-validators)

Comment: Your validator returns two errors: one named maxValue, and the other named message.

Comment: @JBNizet I have update the  function to maxValidator and update the mesage

Comment: But you're still returning an object with two keys, and thus two different validation errors, instead of just one.

Comment: I have check the min validators source and just return an object with one key but `ValidationErrors ` type accept a object so where is my error here , is it correct now ?

Comment: Yes, now it returns an object with a single key. Too bad you chose the same key `max` as the standard max validator, though.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!